# Whose view is not in the window hierarchy? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I want a table view controller to be displayed. Therefore I present the view controller in the `completionwithitemshandler` property below.

```
 let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[memeedimage] , applicationActivities: nil)
        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {
        (activity, success, returneditems, error) in
        println("Activity: \(activity) Success: \(success) Items: \(returneditems) Error: \(error)")
        self.save()
        activityViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        let memevc:MemeTableViewController  = MemeTableViewController()
        activityViewController.presentViewController(memevc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

But I get the following runtime error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MemeMe.MemeTableViewController: 0x7fc4b6179600> on <UIActivityViewController: 0x7fc4b6148180> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

So I believe that it's something to do with my unwrapping of the meme object which has an optional data type.

```
 func save(){
        var meme : MemeObject?
        if let memez = meme{
          meme = MemeObject(textFieldtop : texfieldtop.text! ,textFieldbottom : textfieldbottom.text!  ,image : imagePickerView.image! , memedImage : generateMemedImage())
            (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).memes.append(meme!)
        }
        else{
            println("Optionals man")
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are dismissing the UIActivityViewController, then trying to present another view controller from it. Instead what you want is to present your new view controller from the same view controller you are presenting the activity view controller from.

For example, you can present the new view controller after the activity view controller dismiss is done:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[memeedimage] , applicationActivities: nil)
        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {
        (activity, success, returneditems, error) in
        println("Activity: \(activity) Success: \(success) Items: \(returneditems) Error: \(error)")
        self.save()
        activityViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
           let memevc:MemeTableViewController  = MemeTableViewController()
        self.presentViewController(memevc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Note: In your initial "presentViewController" you didn't need to use self.presentViewController() but because the new call is inside a block using self.presentViewController() makes it explicit that it's the self that should present it.

Comment: What's the ^ for the completion parameter supposed to mean?

Comment: @SyedAriff Sorry, I wrote the post on the fly here and was stuck in the Objective-C block world. I updated the post to just have the Swift-style closure.